# Address: call to non-contract error during hardhat test deploing

Tags: tokens

I got an error during hardhat test deploing contract due to i passed a tokens addresses in params
[image: Hardhat error during deploing contract constructor]

So, how can i pass tokens addresses in constructor params?
[image: This constructor]

Comment: All contracts are just `address` types with some extra decorations. So to pass a contract, you need to use an `address` type, as you've used. The problem must be somewhere else - maybe the contract hasn't been deployed properly before deploying this contract.

Comment: This is the single contract. There are no any other contracts. So, it is something else. May be i have to deploy tokens? Just write ERC20 basic contracts, deploy, and use their addresses?